# Put text in line with top of select box

Tags: html, css

I want to have my text in line with the top of the multiple select box, but it defaults to the bottom. How can I do this? I was also wondering why it defaults to the bottom, I would have thought it would be more common to have it at the top, ie. A label that describes what is in the select box.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label> 
        <span>Choose multiple options: </span> 
        <select name="options" multiple>
            <option value="all">ALL</option>
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <span>Choose file: </span> <input type="file"></input>
    </label>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sionnach733/cK8yc/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
span, input {        
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dKyEf/)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `display: block;` on your labels and the widths of both li and label and it works.

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li {  
  padding-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add an id to the span as below:

```
<span id="top">Choose multiple options: </span>
```

then add CSS:

```
#top{
    vertical-align: top;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a CSS property [`vertical-align: top;`](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).

Try with this :

```
span, input{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cK8yc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use table as the following

html :

```
<div>
    <table width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="250" valign="top">
                &nbsp; <span>Choose multiple options: </span> 
            </td>
            <td align="left" width="250" valign="top">
            <select name="options" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="all">ALL</option>
                <option value="option1">option1</option>
                <option value="option2">option2</option>
                <option value="option3">option3</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="250" valign="top">
            &nbsp; <span>Choose file: </span> 
            </td>
            <td align="left" width="250" valign="top">
           <input type="file"></input>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

table have aproperty valign="top" it will help you